# making square axes plot with log2 scales in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

I'd like to make a square axis scatter plot with matplotlib. Normally using `set_scale("log")` works great, but it limits me to log10. I'd like to make the plot in log2. I saw the solution here: [How to produce an exponentially scaled axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899516/how-to-produce-an-exponentially-scaled-axis)

but it is quite complicated and does not work if you have 0 values in your arrays, which I do. I'd like to simply ignore those like other numpy functions do.

For example:

```
log2scatter(data1, data2)
```

where data1 and data2 contain 0s should have a logarithmic scale on the x and y axis, with logarithmic spaced ticks. Just like log10, except log2...

Comment: Logs are only defined for positive arguments. This holds irrespective of the base, i.e. it holds for natural logs, log base 10, log base 2 etc. Hence you just can't plot something which has zeros in a logscale, unless you do something to these zero values.

Comment: Use the answer from that question but filter out the y-values that are 0 and their corresponding x values first (that's how numpy ignores them anyway).

Comment: What's an elegant way to do that in numpy? The filtering complicates the code since now I have to have a copy of the array unfiltered, and a copy filtered...

Answer (score 67):

**Matplotlib >= 3.3**:

Specify `base=2`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log', base=2)
ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)

ax.plot(range(1024))
plt.show()
```

**Matplotlib < 3.3**:

Specify `basex=2` and/or `basey=2` for the x- and y-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)

ax.plot(range(1024))
plt.show()
```

[image]

For the zero-crossing behavior, what you're referring to is a "Symmetric Log" plot (a.k.a. "symlog").  For whatever it's worth, data isn't filtered out, it's just a linear plot near 0 and a log plot everywhere else.  It's the scale that changes, not the data.

Normally you'd just do `ax.set_xscale('symlog', basex=2)` but using a non-10 base appears to be buggy at the moment for symlog plots.

**Edit**:
Heh! The bug appears to be due to a classic mistake: using a mutable default argument.
I've filed a bug report, but if you feel like fixing it, you'll need to make a minor edit to `lib/matplotlib/ticker.py`, around line 1376, in the `__init__` method of `SymmetricalLogLocator`.

Instead of

```
def __init__(self, transform, subs=[1.0]):
    self._transform = transform
    self._subs = subs
    ...
```

Change it to something similar to:

```
def __init__(self, transform, subs=None):
    self._transform = transform
    if subs is None:
        self._subs = [1.0]
    else:
        self._subs = subs
    ....
```

With that change made, it behaves as expected...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('symlog', basex=2)
ax.set_yscale('symlog', basey=2)

x = np.arange(-1024, 1024)
ax.plot(x, x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I get really strange default x and y limits using base=2 (and actually even without it). It doesn't set it to be the smallest values in either dimension. It picks really strange limits that hide most of the data. How can this be fixed aside from manually setting x/y limits?

Comment: Shouldn't have to override/hack a class in matplotlib to make a freakin' scatter plot in log2 versus log2... it's so sad and frustrating. :(

Comment: The symlog part is a bug.  The limits you're referring to are just the way that limits behave for a log plot.  They "snap" to the nearest power of the base.  If you want the limits to strictly end at the min and max of the data, then specify `ax.axis('tight')`.

Comment: Use `base=2` in `matplotlib >= 3.3` instead of `basex=2` and `basey=2`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using `plt.xscale`, you still need to specify `basex`, not `base`:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887544/making-square-axes-plot-with-log2-scales-in-matplotlib#comment119551375_8888110) suggested. This depends on the matplotlib version. Right now the code above will produce `TypeError: LogScale.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'basex'`

Comment: plt.xscale('log', base=2) worked for me