# How to set the tick scale as the power of 2 in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot a figure whose xtick values grow at the power of 2.

For example,

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64],
    'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})
```

What I expect is a figure like this,
[image]

For tidy data like the sample above, I can just create an auxiliary column `x2` of 1~6 in this dataframe and then set the xticklabels of the figure to 2^1~2^6. However, this workaround doesn't apply to situations with other values like 3, 7 or 30.

It seems that matplotlib only supports a log scale. How can I achieve a tick with a power scale of 2?

Comment: *with other values like 3, 7 or 30* you're talking about number of *x* values and not the wanted power scale, right?

Comment: Looks duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8887544).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particularly trick question (which I did not expected to be ^^).

OK, let's start with a few hints for reading: You want to set the x/y scale: [.matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale()](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html). While there are a couple of standard scales (the default is obviously `'liner'`, one can set a custom scale. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/scales.html) are some nice examples.

Basically, you define two functions with the *forward* transformation and with the *inverse* of it.
Afterwards you need to set the ticks correctly (because you apply the transformation *after* plotting, the ticks remain the same (but not at the same position due to the transformation). One has two options for this:

- setting the ticks manually `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks()`, or
- by setting  the *locator* of the axis: `matplotlib.axes.Axes.xaxis.set_major_locator()`. This is recommended if you use grids. But as my knowledge is limited, I appreciate a more detailed explanation (because now I am also curious about this feature ^^)

And now comes the tricky part: formatting the tick-labels to represent a `'2^x'`. I didn't came across a better idea than setting them explicitly as strings. It seems that one can change the general format only within restricted limits, see [`matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html), where one can choose if and when a scientific notation should be used (i.e. displaying a `'10^x'` at the bottom right). Let me know if there is a more generic solution for this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

# create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [2**x for x in range(1,10)],
    'y': list(range(1,10))
})

def forward(x):
    return np.log2(x)


def inverse(x):
    return 2**x

# open figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
axs = ax.flatten()
for i in range(0,4):
    # plot data
    axs[i].plot(df['x'],df['y'])
    if i > 0:
        # set scale function
        axs[i].set_xscale('function', functions=(forward,inverse))
    if i > 1:
        # set ticks
        # - OPTION 1
        axs[i].set_xticks(df['x'])
        # - OPTION 2
      axs[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(2**np.arange(1,10)))
    if i > 2:
        # est tick labels
        axs[i].set_xticklabels( [f"2^{j:.0f}" for j in np.log2(df['x'])] )

plt.show()
```